# Vite (in Laravel) with AlpineJS not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-vite

I've moved from Laravel Mix to Laravel Vite per the migration instructions. Everything is compiling and working, except for Alpine. In my console I get the following.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Alpine`

**resources/app.js**

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
window.Alpine = Alpine;

// Stores need to be defined before Alpine.start()
import './alpine-stores/modal';

Alpine.start();
```

**alpine-stores/modal**

```js
Alpine.store('modal', {
    active: false,
    id: null,
    open(id) {
        this.active = true
        this.id = id
        document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden')
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('modalopened'))
    },
    close() {
        this.active = false
        this.id = null
        document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('modalclosed'))
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you show your config/vite.php?

Comment: Not sure if _stores_ are similar to _extensions_, but if so, then according to the docs, it needs to happen before the `window.Alpine` assignment.

Comment: I have ‘fixed’ it by adding `import Alpine from ‘alpinejs’` to the modal file (I have multiple of those and added it to all of them). Not sure if this is the right way to do it but works now…

Answer (score 0):

Due to vite we cannot use require statement. So while separating file for data and store is more complicated. I cannot found any official information on alpinejs website. I also pass through same problem and solve this type of problem in this way.

**alpine-data**

```
export default () => ({ 
    active: false,
    id: null,
    open(id) {
        this.active = true
        this.id = id
        document.body.classList.add('overflow-hidden')
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('modalopened'))
    },
    close() {
        this.active = false
        this.id = null
        document.body.classList.remove('overflow-hidden')
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('modalclosed'))
    }
})
```

**resources/app.js**

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs'
window.Alpine = Alpine

// Stores need to be defined before Alpine.start()
import modal from './alpine-stores/modal.js'
Alpine.data('modal', modal)

Alpine.start()
```

**For alpine store don't use arrow function**

```
export default ({
    .....
})
```